# Skip certain lines in __setitem__ when it's called from within __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to create a class for storing time series data. For this I started by subclassing UserDict from the collections library.

The thing with time series data is that I need to keep it in the correct order. Since Python dictionaries maintain the order of insertion, this is not a problem as long as I order the items correctly before creating the object. And I have already written quite a few methods and all of them work correctly.

Now I'm trying to implement `__setitem__` in this class and that's where I'm facing the issue. The only way I can retain the order is to basically rebuild the dictionary and assign it back to `self.data`. This works correctly.

However, since setitem gets called from `__init__`, this makes object instantiation ridiculously slow.

Here's a minimal replication of my code

```
from collections import UserDict
from typing import List
import datetime

def parse_date(date: datetime.datetime):
    if isinstance(date, datetime.datetime):
        return date
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')

class TimeSeries(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, data: List[tuple]):
        ts_data = sorted([(parse_date(dt), val) for dt, val in data])
        super().__init__(ts_data)
        
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = parse_date(key)
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.data = dict(sorted(self.data.items()))
```

for a list containing 7500 items, this code takes about 2.1 seconds on my computer to initialize the object. However, if I remove the last line, it takes about 60 ms.

Since the last line is not adding any value during `__init__` and is only necessary when `__setitem__` is called directly like `my_object['2022-01-01] = 35`, is there a way to skip this line when it's called from `__init__`?

Comment: What is the point of `self.data`? You don't seem to access it ever. Secondly, you can just subclass `dict` directly these days.

Comment: @AKX you *can* but it usually takes much more work, you can't just override `__setitem__`, for example, and expect *other* dict methods to use your `__setitem__` (because `dict` objcts use internal methods)

Comment: Basicaly, you probably shouldn't be using a `dict` if you want a *sorted* data structure. If you want `__setitem__` to work efficiently. But what's the point of inheriting from `UserDict`? Why should this be a `dict` subclass at all? Why not implement your own structure if you know you can just sort upfront and just expose your own mutator methods

Comment: I need this to be a dict to keep lookups fast. I have methods which rely on it. To give an example, say you want 1-year return as on 01-Jan-2022, but there's no data on 01-Jan-2021 on account of that being a Sunday (so no stock price data). My method will automatically lookup the previous/next available date and calculate the returns. This is efficient in a Dict, a list of tuples changes the lookups from O(1) to O(n) making them prohibitively slow.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I tried making it an independent class, without subclassing UserDict, and everything worked with minor changes and my issue is also resolved. Only minor issue is that type checking this class against `Mapping` class no longer works. But I can live with that.